# How to include "Android" folder to Android Studio (ZXing)

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, android-studio

I added "core.jar" to my project. I am trying [this](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.ch/p/android-barcode-scan-using-zxing-library.html) to implement:

I got an error for this:

```
android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
(captureactivity not found)
```

.

I downloaded this [bundle](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-2.2.zip&can=2&q=):

There is a folder "Android" which contains "CaputreActivity, ecc"... but I dont know how to add in "Android Studio" as libruary.

I tried this: right click on prject --> open module settings --> libruary --> add --> java --> then I selected the "Android" folder, then it asked me to which module...

but I am getting the same error even after adding like that...

any one know how to resolve?

Comment: Don't add android/. It's our app, and you're not supposed to clone it or use it like a library.

Comment: what should I add instead of this: android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"?

Comment: Don't add anything like this. Write your own app. Please don't start by copying ours because it will cause trouble for us. But you can reuse bits once you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I fallowed this tutorial: http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/

which worked fine for me

Comment: it worked fine until i reached the part where the folders were supposed to appear like a package (ie like [this](http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/) pic.. but in android studio they [appeared](http://imgeasy.com/images/QHoE7.png) separately.. any idea why?